# Accessing outer class from within inner class using outerClass.this

Tags: java, this, inner-classes, outer-classes

The -non-static- inner class has a full accessibility to all regular members of the outer class. but there is another way to access these members using the (outerClass.this.regularMember).., have a look on the following code:

```
public class Car {
  int x = 3;
  public static int hp =6;
  public void move()
  {
    System.out.println(hp);
  }

  public  class Engine{
     public int hp =5;
     public int capacity; 
     public void start()
     {
        Car.this.move(); // or we can use only move();
     }

  }
}
```

1. Could you please explain me if there would be any practical difference between using `Car.this.move();`  and `move();`
2. How can you explain this syntax of **Car.this.** ,  cause as far as I understand **this** here refers to an **object of Type Engine** but then if I used another reference say by doing `Engine smallEngine = new Engine();`then  **this** keyword is not substitutable by **smallEngine** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your `Engine` class has a `move` method, then `move()` would be different from `Car.this.move()`.
2. `this` means the current instance.  When you want to refer to the outer class, you  are allowed to qualify the `this` keyword with the outer class to refer to the outer class's instance.  The important thing to remember is that an instance of `Engine` (since it is not static) is always accompanied by an instance of `Car` and so you can refer to it.

You are not allowed to say `OuterClass.smallEngine.move()` because that would conflict with the syntax for accessing a static public field of `OuterClass`.

If `OuterClass` had a field like this:

```
 public static String smallEngine;
```

...then the above syntax would be ambigious.  Since `this` is a keyword, you cannot have a field named `this` and therefore the syntax `OuterClass.this` will never be ambigious.

Comment: But then do I understand that ( outerClass.this ) is merely like a keyword (ex: super) in this context ? ..., and further more what do you say about " this keyword is not substitutable by smallEngine " - in the original question .., thx in advance for helping me out.

Comment: `OuterClass.this` basically means the "current instance of OuterClass" (which only works when you are in an inner class of that class).  Clarified the other case in the answer.